# AKS, WIndows Node, dns does not resolve service until fully qualified name is used

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

AKS Cluster with multiple node pools of linux and windows.
Kafka Client: Confluent.Kafka 1.4.4

Trying to resolve a kafka service named "tt-kafka-kafka-bootstrap.shared".

From with in windows pod - FAILS TO RESOLVE:

```
kubectl exec -it test-print-7f6b64dc4f-4z7lt --namespace test -- nslookup tt-kafka-kafka-bootstrap.shared
Server: kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.0.0.10

*** kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local can't find tt-kafka-kafka-bootstrap.shared: Non-existent domain
```

BUT IF I QUALIFY THE SERVICE ADDRESS WITH svc.cluster.local, IT RESOLVES:

```
kubectl exec -it test-print-7f6b64dc4f-4z7lt --namespace test -- nslookup tt-kafka-kafka-bootstrap.shared.svc.cluster.local
Server: kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.0.0.10

Name: tt-kafka-kafka-bootstrap.shared.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.0.192.149
```

FROM With in LINUX POD - RESOLVES FINE:

```
root@test-worker-t1-0:/app# nslookup tt-kafka-kafka-bootstrap.shared
Server: 10.0.0.10
Address: 10.0.0.10#53

Name: tt-kafka-kafka-bootstrap.shared.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.0.192.149
```

Comment: From Windows containers within kubernetes, you need to use the complete FQDN (service-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local) to resolve it. If you want to reach a service within the same namespace using "service-name" will resolve just fine.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out windows can not resolve name spaces with in the kubernetes.

> Please refer to following K8 documentation for more information on
> Windows containers in Kubernetes:
> https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/windows/intro-windows-in-kubernetes/#dns-limitations